# Are galvanized pipes allowed in residential water delivery pipes in NYC?

Tags: new-york-state, property, water

Some residential properties in New York City still have galvanized pipes for the inlet water line.  Since heavy metals from the galvanization can leach into the water, [this kind of pipe is no longer specified as an allow building materials according to NYC plumbing code.](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dob/downloads/pdf/plumbing_code.pdf)

- § PC 605 *does not* specify an allowance for galvanized parts, in
  piping, fitting or joints.
- $ PC 605.3 has a table that does not specify galvanization as an allowed material.  This is in context to [the containing] Section 6, which regards Water Supply and Distribution.
- § PC 702 *does* allow galvanization in
  **drainage**.
- All other usages in this doc deal with non-water systems, or non-inflows.

But in the plumbing code I cannot find a clause section for grandfathering existing galvanized piping.

- Does a grandfathing clause exist in a superseding city code or law?
- Where might I find the change in law that first disallowed galvanized pipes in this usage? (Wherein may also have been specified how to handle existing installations)

Comment: Please identify the specific code section of interest.

Comment: FYI, you might actually get a faster answer to this at http://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @daffy done.  But, my 'section of interest' is any one indicating that galvanization is *allowed.*  I think, *if it exists at all*, it will be an an amending document, that I don't yet know about.

Comment: After looking at those code sections it would seem to be that the NYC PC has adopted ASTM standards. The publications of that  organization might provide some explanation as to why galvanized pipe is not specifically approved for that application. I don't think I have access to any database that would have the revision history.  As to a grandfather clause, see NYC PC §101.2 ("Plumbing systems in existing buildings undergoing repair, alteration, or additions, and change of occupancy shall be permitted to comply with the existing building provisions of the New York city building code. ")

Comment: No idea of the legality in NYC but the engineering reason is that domestic water chemically attacks galvanised pipe. In Australia it is permitted on "dead legs" for fire systems (because there is no regular introduction of new chemicals and the static water becomes "inert") but not for anything else.

Comment: @daffy presumably "existing" means "existing at the time of original installation"?

Comment: Presumably, but if you're going to rely on it, it would probably be wise to talk to someone who would know positively. You might be able to get this answer from a City office, or a plumber or contractor. Failing that, a brief consultation (very, very brief for this single question) with an NYC construction lawyer would do the trick.